# Finding the top of a MotionEvent

Tags: android

What I need to do is find the top pixel of a `MotionEvent`. I'm trying to have a `View` appear over top of where the touch happens, high enough that it isn't obstructed by your finger. All I can find in the API is meant for finding the center of the touch.

The idea is to bring up a tooltip above where the user touches. The base layout is a `FrameLayout`, so adding in the view is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding but can you not just add a preset margin of a finger's worth of pixels on to the center of the MotionEvent?

Comment: The problem is finding a finger's worth of pixels. A higher resolution display will need a higher offset, but the same offset might be too high for a low resolution display.

Comment: If you made it by creating a transparent png that was a vertical rectangle, put your non-transparent section in the top half of the rectangle, and leave the bottom transparent. Then if you make multiple of these and put them in drawable-mdpi, hdpi, ldpi etc.. it will adjust to the screen size. so if you make the bottom half of the rectangle be roughly finger sized it should make sure to push the actual image you care about north a bit so the user can see it.

Comment: Either that or preset offsets to the x,y co-ords of the touch based on the resolution would work. But, if the user was using a stylus or just has a really fat finger, the offsets wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding correctly, you want to show a view over the touched point.

So you just can get the x,y of the motionEvent action_up and then place your view on x - layout heigh and y - layoutWidth.

Can you extend your question so i can drop some lines of code?

its a fragment? its a view that you want to add to the current layout?

Regards.

Comment: It's not a fragment. The layout is a FrameLayout, so adding it is easy. I'd prefer if it wasn't obstructed by the touch (by finger, styles, etc), so it needs to take into account the size of the touch.